# Angular2- How to extract/save/capture selected form fields in JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I am learning angular2 and got stuck with a scenario where I have developed a form where I am populating values through JSON.  I have few form fields and few text fields where user can enter any values and select any option. Based on the values selected and entered,I want to capture those form values in form of JSON. I think I have to use Observables but not very sure how to use that.How can I do that?

Below is the code that I have written.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div *ngFor="let question of questions>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
             <md-input placeholder="{{question.displayKey }}"></md-input>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row row-bordered">
          <div class="col-md-8"> {{question.displayKey }}</div>
          <div class="col-md-4">  
             <md-radio-group>
               <span>
                 <md-radio-button *ngFor="let option of question.choices" name="{{option.displayKey}}" [value]="option.displayKey" aria-label="Yes" tabindex="0">{{option.displayKey}}</md-radio-button>
               </span>
             </md-radio-group>
          </div>                            
      </div>                        
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JSON-

```
"questions": [
  {
    "code": "12345",
    "displayKey": "Question1?",
    "required": true,
    "questionType": "Boolean",
    "choices": [
       {
         "choiceCode": "true",
         "displayKey": "Yes"
       },
       {
         "choiceCode": "false",
         "displayKey": "No"
       }
    ],                           
  },
  {
    "code": "aw345y",
    "displayKey": "Question2?",
    "required": true,
    "questionType": "Boolean",
    "choices": [
       {
         "choiceCode": "true",
         "displayKey": "Yes"
       },
       {
         "choiceCode": "false",
         "displayKey": "No"
       }
     ],                           
   }
 ]
```

Comment: You should get this functionality "for free" once you use either template forms (ngModel) or reactive forms (FormBuilder). That will be the "value" of the form.

Answer (score 0):

`<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(form.value)">`

and in ts file

```
submitForm(value){
    console.log(value);
}
```